# How can I configure Visual Studio Code to recognize files with extensions other than .js as Javascript

Tags: visual-studio-code

We have a QA tool (SmartBear's TestComplete) that uses javascript as a scripting language, but names the file with a ".sj" extension instead of ".js". I would like to use Visual Studio Code to edit those files, with all the nice intellisense and other tooling that comes with it, but I can't figure out how to configure it to recognize .sj files as javascript files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, just for future readers that may be searching for the same thing.

[According to a tweet from @code](https://twitter.com/code/status/637829003022217216), this is not yet possible, but is coming "soon".